# Why are too many open, fstat, mmap, and close calls for lib files seen in a strace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, strace

strace -v -e trace=desc ls

open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

fstat(3, {st_dev=makedev(8, 1), st_ino=1311343, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=176, st_size=88205, st_atime=2018/08/30-07:23:57.086001060, st_mtime=2018/08/30-07:23:55.777347107, st_ctime=2018/08/30-07:23:56.357637086}) = 0

mmap(NULL, 88205, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f76831d6000

close(3)                                = 0

Comment: You may want to expand on your question. For example, what in this output is "too many" calls? What were you expecting to see, etc.

Comment: I'll also add that you may want to read [ask] for help improving your question.

Comment: A lot of these system calls are done by [ld-linux.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)

Comment: @Hasturkun, Sorry for not adding details earlier. Whenever I execute strace for command - ls, I see that open, fstat, mmap, and close calls are made for - ld.so.cache, libselinux.so.1, libc.so.6, and many other lib.so files before getdents is invoked, which does the primary job for ls command. I want to know why we do operations - open, fstat, mmap, and close on those lib.so files.